# Filter in DIV content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_it_ram/fbC6w/) for searching/filtering the `div` content which I am getting from an XML response. But I have done it for one text box alone. Any one can help me in implementing for next three?

For example:

If I am typing `pd001` it shows the first 2 rows and if I type paste it should reach and filter from the current visible list, not from the whole list.

Kindly help me out on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong then you must be trying to do is that If I search 2 rows based on `pd001` and put `paste` in the next textbox then it should filter only those 2 rows not the entire grid. And the same functionality for all the other textboxes. In fact you need dependencies b/w textboxes.

Try this:

```
    $(".productid").filter(function () {
        $(this).parent().hide();
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(text0) != -1
    }).parent().show();

    $(".product:visible").filter(function () {
       $(this).parent().hide();
       return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(text1) != -1; 
    }).parent().show();

    $(".quantity:visible").filter(function () {
       $(this).parent().hide();
       return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(text2) != -1; 
    }).parent().show();

    $(".amount:visible").filter(function () {
       $(this).parent().hide();
       return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(text3) != -1; 
    }).parent().show();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fbC6w/4/

Comment: Thats want i needed and really thank you so much for the fix. Great Man :)

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering only one column to, it may help you

```
$("#searchone , #searchtwo ,#searchthree ,#searchfour").bind("keyup", function() {

    var map = {
        '.productid': $("#searchone").val().toLowerCase(),
        '.product': $("#searchtwo").val().toLowerCase(),
        '.quantity': $("#searchthree").val().toLowerCase(),
        '.amount': $("#searchfour").val().toLowerCase()
    };
    $('div.new').each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $('div.new').each(function() {
        var parent_div = this;
        $.each(map, function(key, value) {
            $(parent_div).find(key).filter(function() {
                if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toString()) != -1 && value != '') {
                    $(parent_div).show();
                }
            });
        });
    });

});​
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your effort but your code does not provide me the o/p what i am looking out for... filiter is not working as wanted. ANy hw thanks for your effort Ronak :)